# Does MSAL Nuget Package Have Config Issues

Tags: azure-ad-msal

Are there any known issues with the latest MSAL preview Nuget package?  I was able to add it successfully to my project, but now when I go back to manage the Nuget packages for my solution, it won't display anything on the Installed packages page; instead it has an error that says An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.1.1.1-preview0040' from source 'C:\blah'.  In addition, I now can't add any new packages to any projects in my solution because it throws the same error.

Thanks.